# how to access json data globaly

Tags: javascript, jquery

In code below I am trying to retrieve clients machine IP. The problem is in TestIP variable this one shows null when I debug script. How I could assign this value to show clear string with IP after exiting from $.getJSON() function.

```
<script>
var test1 = null;
$(document).ready(function () {

    var inDesignMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value;

    $.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?', function (data) {
        //getting IP correctly                 
        test1 = data.host;
        $('#' + '<%=hdnDeliServerGIP.ClientID%>').val(data.host);
    })
    if (inDesignMode != "1") {
        //should show IP - is Null
        var TestIP = test1;
        //Not getting the value from hidden asp object
        var GIP = $('#' + '<%=hiddenElementIP.ClientID%>').val() != '' ? $('#' + '<%=hdnDeliServerGIP.ClientID%>').val() : 'not set';
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yet another asynchronous issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `getJSON` is an asynchronous call, so your subsequent `if` block is actually called *before* `getJSON` returns. You should move the `if` block *inside* the `getJSON` callback:

```
$.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?', function (data) {
    //getting IP correctly                 
    test1 = data.host;
    $('#' + '<%=hdnDeliServerGIP.ClientID%>').val(data.host);

    if (inDesignMode != "1") {
        //should show IP
        var TestIP = test1;
        //Getting value from hidden asp object
        var GIP = $('#' + '<%=hiddenElementIP.ClientID%>').val() != '' ? $('#' + '<%=hdnDeliServerGIP.ClientID%>').val() : 'not set';
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your code in the `getJSON` callback like,

```
var inDesignMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value;

$.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?', function (data) {
    //getting IP correctly                 
    test1 = data.host;
    $('#' + '<%=hdnDeliServerGIP.ClientID%>').val(data.host);

    // use you code here in callback function
    if (inDesignMode != "1") {
        //should show IP
        var TestIP = test1;
        //Getting value from hidden asp object
        var GIP = $('#' + '<%=hiddenElementIP.ClientID%>').val() != '' ? $('#' + '<%=hdnDeliServerGIP.ClientID%>').val() : 'not set';
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the if statement inside the `$.getJSON` call at the end of the lines you currently have in it. The problem is that `$.getJSON` is asynchronous and so its not necessarily done by the time you are trying to access `test1`

So what you want is:

```
   $.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?', function (data) {
        //getting IP correctly                 
        test1 = data.host;
        $('#' + '<%=hdnDeliServerGIP.ClientID%>').val(data.host);
        if (inDesignMode != "1") {
          //should show IP - is Null
          var TestIP = test1;
          //Not getting the value from hidden asp object
          var GIP = $('#' + '<%=hiddenElementIP.ClientID%>').val() != '' ? $('#' +       '<%=hdnDeliServerGIP.ClientID%>').val() : 'not set';
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a global variable in javascript, we need to declare variable without using "var" keyword.

try using "test1 = null;"

Answer (score 0):

in order to make a js variable globally you need to first declare a variable and then assign you json data onto that, and then you can access that variable globally.

eg:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var inDesignMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value;

    $.ajax({
    url :'http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?',
    async:false,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (data) {
        //getting IP correctly                 
        test = data.host;   
    }});
    if (inDesignMode != "1") {
        //should show IP - is Null
        var TestIP = test1;
        //Not getting the value from hidden asp object
        var GIP = $('#' + '<%=hiddenElementIP.ClientID%>').val() != '' ? $('#' + '<%=hdnDeliServerGIP.ClientID%>').val() : 'not set';
    }
});
```

**Note:- Please define test variable once outside this call in the begining of page**

hope this will help you :)